# Using when and otherwise while converting boolean values to strings in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame in `Pyspark`

```python
df.show()


+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
| id|name|testing|avg_result|score|active|
+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
|  1| sam|   null|      null| null|  true|
|  2| Ram|      Y|      0.05|   10| false|
|  3| Ian|      N|      0.01|    1| false|
|  4| Jim|      N|       1.2|    3|  true|
+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
```

The schema is below:

```python
DataFrame[id: int, name: string, testing: string, avg_result: string, score: string, active: boolean]
```

I want to convert `Y` to `True`, `N` to `False` `true` to `True` and `false` to `False`.

When I do like below:

```python
for col in cols:
    df = df.withColumn(col, f.when(f.col(col) == 'N', 'False').when(f.col(col) == 'Y', 'True').
                       when(f.col(col) == 'true', True).when(f.col(col) == 'false', False).otherwise(f.col(col)))
```

I get below error and there is no change in data frame

```python
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'CASE WHEN (testing = N) THEN False WHEN (testing = Y) THEN True WHEN (testing = true) THEN true WHEN (testing = false) THEN false ELSE testing' due to data type mismatch: THEN and ELSE expressions should all be same type or coercible to a common type;"

+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
| id|name|testing|avg_result|score|active|
+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
|  1| sam|   null|      null| null|  true|
|  2| Ram|      Y|      0.05|   10| false|
|  3| Ian|      N|      0.01|    1| false|
|  4| Jim|      N|       1.2|    3|  true|
+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
```

When I do like below

```python
for col in cols:
    df = df.withColumn(col, f.when(f.col(col) == 'N', 'False').when(f.col(col) == 'Y', 'True').otherwise(f.col(col)))
```

I get below error

```python
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'CASE WHEN if ((isnull(active) || isnull(cast(N as double)))) null else CASE cast(cast(N as double) as double) WHEN cast(1 as double) THEN active WHEN cast(0 as double) THEN NOT active ELSE false THEN False WHEN if ((isnull(active) || isnull(cast(Y as double)))) null else CASE cast(cast(Y as double) as double) WHEN cast(1 as double) THEN active WHEN cast(0 as double) THEN NOT active ELSE false THEN True ELSE active' due to data type mismatch: THEN and ELSE expressions should all be same type or coercible to a common type;"
```

But the data frame changes to

```python
+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
| id|name|testing|avg_result|score|active|
+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
|  1| sam|   null|      null| null|  true|
|  2| Ram|   True|      0.05|   10| false|
|  3| Ian|  False|      0.01|    1| false|
|  4| Jim|  False|       1.2|    3|  true|
+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
```

`New attempt`

```python
for col in cols:
    df = df.withColumn(col, f.when(f.col(col) == 'N', 'False').when(f.col(col) == 'Y', 'True').
                       when(f.col(col) == 'true', 'True').when(f.col(col) == 'false', 'False').otherwise(f.col(col)))
```

`Error received`

```python
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'CASE WHEN if ((isnull(active) || isnull(cast(N as double)))) null else CASE cast(cast(N as double) as double) WHEN cast(1 as double) THEN active WHEN cast(0 as double) THEN NOT active ELSE false THEN False WHEN if ((isnull(active) || isnull(cast(Y as double)))) null else CASE cast(cast(Y as double) as double) WHEN cast(1 as double) THEN active WHEN cast(0 as double) THEN NOT active ELSE false THEN True WHEN if ((isnull(active) || isnull(cast(true as double)))) null else CASE cast(cast(true as double) as double) WHEN cast(1 as double) THEN active WHEN cast(0 as double) THEN NOT active ELSE false THEN True WHEN if ((isnull(active) || isnull(cast(false as double)))) null else CASE cast(cast(false as double) as double) WHEN cast(1 as double) THEN active WHEN cast(0 as double) THEN NOT active ELSE false THEN False ELSE active' due to data type mismatch: THEN and ELSE expressions should all be same type or coercible to a common type;"
```

How can I get the data frame to be like

```python
+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
| id|name|testing|avg_result|score|active|
+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
|  1| sam|   null|      null| null|  True|
|  2| Ram|   True|      0.05|   10| False|
|  3| Ian|  False|      0.01|    1| False|
|  4| Jim|  False|       1.2|    3|  True|
+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
```

Comment: You're mixing the string `"False"` and the boolean `False` in your first attempt. The error means spark doesn't know what to do with strings and booleans in the same column.

Comment: @pault Even if I don't mix the `string` and `boolean` I am still getting error Please have a look at the edited part

Comment: You are still missing a cast in the `otherwise`, but have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51143853/5858851) below as I think there may be better ways to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the issue is a type mismatch. You need to convert the boolean column to a string before doing the comparison. Finally, you need to cast the column to a string in the `otherwise()` as well (you can't have mixed types in a column).

Your code is easy to modify to get the correct output:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

cols = ["testing", "active"]
for col in cols:
    df = df.withColumn(
        col, 
        f.when(
            f.col(col) == 'N',
            'False'
        ).when(
            f.col(col) == 'Y',
            'True'
        ).when(
            f.col(col).cast('string') == 'true',
            'True'
        ).when(
            f.col(col).cast('string') == 'false',
            'False'
        ).otherwise(f.col(col).cast('string'))
    )
df.show()
#+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
#| id|name|testing|avg_result|score|active|
#+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
#|  1| sam|   null|      null| null|  True|
#|  2| Ram|   True|      0.05|   10| False|
#|  3| Ian|  False|      0.01|    1| False|
#|  4| Jim|  False|       1.2|    3|  True|
#+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
```

However, there are some alternative approaches as well. For instance, this is a good place to use [`pyspark.sql.Column.isin()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isin):

```python
df = reduce(
    lambda df, col: df.withColumn(
        col, 
        f.when(
            f.col(col).cast('string').isin(['N', 'false']),
            'False'
        ).when(
            f.col(col).cast('string').isin(['Y', 'true']),
            'True'
        ).otherwise(f.col(col).cast('string'))
    ),
    cols,
    df
)
df.show()
#+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
#| id|name|testing|avg_result|score|active|
#+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
#|  1| sam|   null|      null| null|  True|
#|  2| Ram|   True|      0.05|   10| False|
#|  3| Ian|  False|      0.01|    1| False|
#|  4| Jim|  False|       1.2|    3|  True|
#+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
```

(Here I used `reduce` to eliminate the `for` loop, but you could have kept it.)

You could also use [`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace) but you'd have to first convert the column active to a string:

```python
df = df.withColumn('active', f.col('active').cast('string'))\
    .replace(['Y', 'true',], 'True', subset=cols)\
    .replace(['N', 'false'], 'False', subset=cols)\
df.show()
# results omitted, but it's the same as above
```

Or using `replace` just once:

```python
df = df.withColumn('active', f.col('active').cast('string'))\
    .replace(['Y', 'true', 'N', 'false'], ['True', 'True', 'False', 'False'], subset=cols)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the schema and the transformations applied, there is a type mismatch between String and Boolean returned. E.g. `'N'` is returned as `'False'` (String) and `'false'` is returned as `False` (Boolean)

You can cast the transformed columns to String to convert `Y` to `True`, `N` to `False`, `true` to `True` and `false` to `False`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

data = [
  (1, "sam", None, None, None, True),
  (2, "Ram", "Y", 0.05, 10, False),
  (3, "Ian", "N", 0.01, 1, False),
  (4, "Jim", "N", 1.2, 3, True)
  ]

schema = StructType([
  StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
  StructField("name", StringType(), True),
  StructField("testing", StringType(), True),
  StructField("avg_result", StringType(), True),
  StructField("score", StringType(), True),
  StructField("active", BooleanType(), True)
  ])

df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF(schema)
```

Before applying the transformations

```
>>> df.printSchema()
root
|-- id: integer (nullable = true)
|-- name: string (nullable = true)
|-- testing: string (nullable = true)
|-- avg_result: string (nullable = true)
|-- score: string (nullable = true)
|-- active: boolean (nullable = true)

>>> df.show()
+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
| id|name|testing|avg_result|score|active|
+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
|  1| sam|   null|      null| null|  true|
|  2| Ram|      Y|      0.05|   10| false|
|  3| Ian|      N|      0.01|    1| false|
|  4| Jim|      N|       1.2|    3|  true|
+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
```

Applying transformation with cast in the otherwise clause `.otherwise(f.col(col).cast("string"))`

```
cols = ["testing", "active"]

for col in cols:
    df = df.withColumn(col, 
      f.when(f.col(col) == 'N', 'False')
      .when(f.col(col) == 'Y', 'True')
      .when(f.col(col).cast("string") == 'true', 'True')
      .when(f.col(col).cast("string") == 'false', 'False'))
```

Results

```
>>> df.printSchema()
root
|-- id: integer (nullable = true)
|-- name: string (nullable = true)
|-- testing: string (nullable = true)
|-- avg_result: string (nullable = true)
|-- score: string (nullable = true)
|-- active: string (nullable = true)

>>> df.show()
+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
| id|name|testing|avg_result|score|active|
+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
|  1| sam|   null|      null| null|  True|
|  2| Ram|   True|      0.05|   10| False|
|  3| Ian|  False|      0.01|    1| False|
|  4| Jim|  False|       1.2|    3|  True|
+---+----+-------+----------+-----+------+
```

Comment: your code is working only for `testing column` not for `active` column. In your answer you have `active` column populated as my `required output`. Please check

Comment: @nmr, I have edited the response. Cast the data type before checking. That would avoid the type mismatch errors.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert them to boolean and then back to string.

EDIT: I'm using spark 2.3.0

e.g.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, initcap
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, BooleanType, StringType, StructType, StructField

data = [(1, "Y"), (1, "N"), (2, "false"), (2, "1"), (3, "NULL"), (3, None)]
schema = StructType([StructField("id", IntegerType(), True), StructField("txt", StringType(), True)])
df = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate().createDataFrame(data, schema)
print(df.dtypes)
df.show()
df = df.withColumn("txt", col("txt").cast(BooleanType()))
print(df.dtypes)
df.show()
df = df.withColumn("txt", col("txt").cast(StringType()))
df = df.withColumn("txt", initcap(col("txt")))
print(df.dtypes)
df.show()
```

will give you

```
[('id', 'int'), ('txt', 'string')]

+---+-----+
| id|  txt|
+---+-----+
|  1|    Y|
|  1|    N|
|  2|false|
|  2|    1|
|  3| NULL|
|  3| null|
+---+-----+

[('id', 'int'), ('txt', 'boolean')]

+---+-----+
| id|  txt|
+---+-----+
|  1| true|
|  1|false|
|  2|false|
|  2| true|
|  3| null|
|  3| null|
+---+-----+

[('id', 'int'), ('txt', 'string')]

+---+-----+
| id|  txt|
+---+-----+
|  1| True|
|  1|False|
|  2|False|
|  2| True|
|  3| null|
|  3| null|
+---+-----+
```